# adding indexed values of arrays created in a forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add the values of multiple arrays (one starts out empty, but all the ones I am adding to it are the same length, though it be great if we could come up with something that adds them even if they are all different lengths) - not the sum of all values in each array, instead, sum of the values in the same index. For example:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = [2, 3, 4]
desiredArray = [3, 5, 7]
```

The number of the arrays I will be adding is arbitrary, as they are created based on the users selection. (Based on the length of the array created from the selection). I want to sum the arrays by index to create a new array, and from the new array, I will create a decline curve. When I attempt to add them using "indexSum" I get an array below back full of NaaNs...though they are the correct legth:

```
requestedOil
requestedGas
requestedWater
```

These are the temporary arrays created by the length of the var "values" - these are the ones I am trying to add by respective index to eventually get the ones mentioned above:

```
Oil[well]
Gas[well]
Water[well]
```

THIS IS THE FUNCTON I CURRENTLY HAVE TO ADD ARRAYS AND CALLED WHEN USER MAKES SELECTION FROM multiple-site-selection

```
function updateCurves(){
  var dropdownMenu = document.getElementById("multiple-site-selection").selectedOptions;
  var values = Array.from(dropdownMenu).map(({ value }) => value);
  console.log(values);

  d3.json('./static/wellNames.json').then((data) => { //read in the wellNames.json file, which contains the array "names" with all the well names
    wellOptions = data.names;
    forSelection = wellOptions.map((x) => ({id:x}))
    console.log(forSelection);

  d3.json("./static/all_production.json").then((data) =>{
      var requestedOil = [];
      var requestedGas = []; 
      var requestedWater = [];
      var site_date = [];
      
      var Oil = [];
      var Gas = [];
      var Water = [];
      
      values.forEach((well) => {
          forSelection.forEach((pair) => {
              if(well == Object.values(pair)){
                  Oil[well] = new Array();
                  Gas[well] = new Array();
                  Water[well] = new Array();
                  new Promise ((resolve) => data.forEach((site) => {
                      if(values.length == 1 && well == site[0]){
                          requestedOil.push(site[2]);
                          requestedGas.push(site[3]);
                          requestedWater.push(site[4]);
                          site_date.push(site[8])}
                      else if(values.length > 1 && well == site[0]){
                          indexSum = (a1, a2) => a1.map((v, i) => i + a2[v]);
                          Oil[well].push(site[2])
                          requestedOil = indexSum(Oil[well], requestedOil);
                          Gas[well].push(site[3])
                          requestedGas = indexSum(Gas[well], requestedGas);
                          Water[well].push(site[4])
                          requestedWater = indexSum(Water[well], requestedWater);
                          site_date.push(site[8])}
                      else{}
                          resolve()}))//PROMISE CLOSED
                      } //IF CLOSED
                  })//forSelection (dic containing names of well selected) closed
                  console.log(Oil[well]);
              }); //values.forEach closed
```

THIS CODE CURRENTLY WORKS AS I AM NOT ADDING ANY ARRAYS AND IT IS CALLED AS SOON AS THE WEBPAGE LOADS

```
    //FUNCTION TO CREATE DROP DOWN VALUES
    function createDropdownOptions() {
      var selector = d3.select("#multiple-site-selection"); //select dropdown <select> in well.html with id:"siteSelection"
      d3.json('./static/wellNames.json').then((data) => { //read in the wellNames.json file, which contains the array "names" with all the well names
        var wellOptions = data.names;
        wellOptions.forEach((well) => {
          selector
          .append('option')
          .text(well)
          .property('Value', well);
        })
      })
    };
    
    createDropdownOptions(); //CALL FUNCTION TO CREATE DROPDOWN MENU VALUES
    
    // //FUNCTION TO CREATE HOME/SUMMARY CURVES
    function curvesHome() {
      d3.json("./static/all_production.json").then((data) =>{ //THIS WORKS!!!
        var site_oil = [];
        var site_gas = [];
        var site_water = [];
        summarySiteDate = [];
    
        new Promise ((resolve) => data.forEach(site => {if (site[0]==="Summary") {
          site_oil.push(site[2]);
          site_gas.push(site[3]);
          site_water.push(site[4]);
          summarySiteDate.push(site[8]);
        } resolve()}));
        
        //CALL FUNCTION TO CREATE DROPDOWN MENU VALUES
        var mostRecentEntry = summarySiteDate[0]; //MOST RECENT DATE WITHOUT HOUR AS VARIABLE
        var addingHours = "T00:00"; //HOURS TO ADD TO MOST RECENT DATE - NEEDED TO NORMALIZE FROM ORIGINAL 19 HOUR FORMAT
        var nextYear = mostRecentEntry.concat(addingHours); //DATE AND HOUR AS SINGLE VARIABLE TO MAKE INTO DATE
    
        var mostRecentDate = new Date(nextYear); //MAKE VARIABLE INTO DATE
        var nextYearsDate = new Date(mostRecentDate.setFullYear(mostRecentDate.getFullYear() + 1)); //GET YEAR FROM MOST RECENT DATE AND ADD A YEAR
    
        var nextYear= nextYearsDate.getFullYear() //GET NEXT YEARS DATE
        var nextMonth= nextYearsDate.getMonth() + 1 // GET NEXTS YEARS MONTH, ADD ONE BECAUSE MONTHS ARE INDEXED AT 0
        var nextDate= nextYearsDate.getDate() //GET NEXT YEARS DATE
    
        nextYearGraph = `${nextYear}-${nextMonth}-${nextDate}`; // CREATE FULL DATE FOR NEXT YEAR IN RIGHT FORMAT FOR AXIS
        console.log(`${nextYearGraph} is a year from the most recent production date. This is from curvesHome()`);
    
        var dataOil = [{
          x: summarySiteDate,
          y: site_oil,
          type: "line",
          line:
          {color: "green"}
        }];
        var layoutOil = {
          title: "Oil BBL",
          yaxis: {
            type: 'log',
            autorange: true
          },
          xaxis: {
            autorange: false,
            range: [summarySiteDate[summarySiteDate.length-1], nextYearGraph]
          }
        };
        Plotly.newPlot("oilDeclineCurve", dataOil, layoutOil); 
        
        // gas decline curve data
        var dataGas = [{
          x: summarySiteDate,
          y: site_gas,
          type: "line",
          line: {color: "red"} 
        }];
        var layoutGas = {
          title: "Gas BBL",
          yaxis: {
            type: 'log',
            autorange: true
            },
          xaxis: {
            autorange: false,
            range: [summarySiteDate[summarySiteDate.length-1], nextYearGraph]
            }
          }; 
          Plotly.newPlot("gasDeclineCurve", dataGas, layoutGas); 
      
        // water decline curve data
        var dataWater = [{
          x: summarySiteDate,
          y: site_water,
          type: "line" }
        ]; 
        var layoutWater = {
          title: "Water BBL",
          yaxis: {
            type: 'log',
            autorange: true
            },
          xaxis: {
            autorange: false,
            range: [summarySiteDate[summarySiteDate.length-1], nextYearGraph]
            }
          };
        Plotly.newPlot("waterDeclineCurve", dataWater, layoutWater);
      })};
```

I have both HTML sand JS in my code, so it is probably best if you have the whole thing to better understand what I am doing and trying to do. Here are my links:

[My repo:](https://github.com/gabrielavalos/HAWKWOOD)
[My GitPage](https://gabrielavalos.github.io/HAWKWOOD/well.html)

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Consider adding your code using code snippet.

Comment: Avoid having links to code. If short enough, you should add the code of the method that you are currently using to your post so it is easier for people to help

Comment: We need more information. How does the user select the number of arrays and their elements?

Comment: @AvalosG Will the arrays be of equal length?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee, yes, always of equal length

Comment: @BlackMath from the multiple-site-selection select in the HMLT, just added more code to clear things up

Comment: btw, you don't need a `Promise` in there anything that happens inside the function will execute synchronously (inline), so it just adds complexity. You would use those when dealing with async code, like an ajax request. However, that would break the result, since the promise is populating your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Since the arrays are of equal lengths, you can simply use `Array#map`.

```js
const 
  indexSum = (a1, a2) => a1.map((v, i) => v + a2[i]),
  desiredArray = indexSum([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

console.log(desiredArray)
```

Comment: @AvalosG Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: well the names of my arrays are created dynamically in the values.forEach...so I am confused as how I would call those into the function you shared. Can you further explain that, please?

Comment: @AvalosG I've updated my answer please check, simply create a function and pass the arrays into it, the function would return the resultant array.

Comment: This doesn't work, it concats the last array to the previous one as its last index. Any ide why? Or any other suggestions? I will continue on playing with the code you provided and hopefully come up with a solution.

Comment: @AvalosG Is your problem solved or do you still need some help?

Comment: I still need help, I included the code you suggested (updated above)...and I get an array full of NaaNs back.

Comment: @AvalosG How are you using the function? What arrays are you passing to the function?

Comment: The ones created from the "data.forEach((site)"  if the selection matches site[0] the I   "Oil[well].push(site[2])" and I add it to "requestedOil". Does that make sense? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @AvalosG Could you `console.log` the arrays that you're passing to the function and paste it here. If the arrays are large just paste the first two values from both the arrays.

Comment: line 139 console.log(Oil[well]);                                                                                            line 140 console.log(requestedOil);                                                                  
curves.js:139 (1076) [9.98, 6.65, 23.29]
curves.js:140 (1076) [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
curves.js:139 (1076) [36.32, 30.06, 25.7,]
curves.js:140 (1076) [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,]

Comment: Are these values Strings or Numbers? @AvalosG

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that bases length off of first array length and doesn't care about the number of input arrays

```js
function stackSum(arr) {
  return arr[0].map((a, i) => {
    let r = 0;
    arr.forEach(b, j) => r+=arr[j][i]);
    return r;
  })
}
console.log(stackSum([
  [1,1,1],
  [1,2,2],
  [2,2,3],
  [3,7,7]
]).join(','));

console.log(stackSum([
  [1,2,3],
  [2,3,4]
]).join(','));
```